# Swap hex digit pairs in bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary hex string, for example: `b'\x914\x05\x11\x11\x95h\xf5'` (the `f` is a filler in this case), and the expected result would be `b'\x914\x05\x11\x11\x95h\xf5'` → `91340511119568F5` → `19435011115986515`.

To do this with the string and a loop is probably not the best solution (there are million on records), what would be a better way?

Edit: Forgot to mention the f is just a filler added from the server (network switch) to provide an even number for the switching (as mentioned by mkrieger)

Comment: How should the code know that the `f` does not belong in the result?

Comment: You aren't swapping byte pairs; you are swapping hex digits *within* a single byte.

Comment: Actual byte-swapping can be done with `struct.unpack` and `struct.pack`, treating the original byte string as sequence of short ints using one endianness (e.g., big-endian), then repackaging them as short ints of the other  endianness (i.e., little-endian).

Comment: What exactly should be the result, a string, or a number, or another `bytes` object?

Comment: Where are the last two digits `15` in the desired result coming from?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Absolutely my bad, the f is just a filler from the server creating the number so I get an even number of digits to switch around (I thought at first it's the hex F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a `bytes` object. When iterating over it you get integer values:

```
>>> s = b'\x914\x05\x11\x11\x95h\xf5'
>>> list(s)  # equivalent to [b for b in s]
[145, 52, 5, 17, 17, 149, 104, 245]
```

To swap the two "nibbles" (the two 4-bit halves) of a byte, you can use bitwise operations, given that the byte is represented by its integer value. To select the higher-valued nibble, use a bit mask `0xF0` with bitwise *and* (`&`), and to select the lower-valued nibble, use `0x0F`. Then shift them by 4 bits in the respective directions and combine them again with bitwise *or* (`|`):

```
def swap_nibbles(b: int) -> int:
    return ((b & 0xF0) >> 4) | ((b & 0x0F) << 4)
```

Now you can do this for all bytes in `s` to get a list of byte values with swapped nibbles:

```
>>> swapped_nibbles = [swap_nibbles(b) for b in s]
# [25, 67, 80, 17, 17, 89, 134, 95]
```

Now you just need to reassemble these numbers to your desired result. I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want, so here are some options:

- To get another `bytes` object: Just use the `bytes` constructor.

  ```
  >>> bytes(swapped_nibbles)
  b'\x19CP\x11\x11Y\x86_'
  ```
- To get an integer: Use the `int.from_bytes` constructor with big-endian byte order.

  ```
  >>> int.from_bytes(swapped_nibbles, byteorder='big')
  1820386708623558239  # == 0x194350111159865F
  ```
- To get a hex string: Use `hex` on the above integer, or build it from the individual bytes:

  ```
  >>> ''.join(f'{b:02X}' for b in swapped_nibbles)
  '194350111159865F'
  ```

It's not clear to me what exactly the rules are for excluding the last `F` from the result, so you would have to add this logic yourself somehow.